# Azure DevOps acesDictionary for repoV2

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

I have accidentally changed permissions on repoV2 when I was trying to change the permissions on a specific Repo via REST. Instead of targeting **repoV2/*ProjectGuid***, I ended up updating **repoV2**. Can someone tell me how I can reset it? I dont have the previous values.

URL: https://dev.azure.com/*yourcompany*/_apis/accesscontrollists/2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87?api-version=6.0-preview.1

If you search for **"token":"repoV2"**, there is an acesDictionary object associated with it. How can I get it reset to what it previously was?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 1):

I added the necessary group SID Identifiers to the acesDictionary. Also removed the ones that were added incorrectly. Then saving it back seems to have taken it to an expected state. The 3 group permissions added back were based on what I saw on repos that had disabled inheritance....using these as a model, I determined that the 3 groups above were what needed to be at the repoV2 level. If there any others that need to be added, please let me know.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such document about that.

I think you could just use [Postman](https://blog.postman.com/how-to-use-api-keys/) to writeback the value into the api:

```
{
  "count": "xxx",
  "value": [{ "inheritPermissions":true,
              "token":"repoV2",
              "acesDictionary":{"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.xxx@Live.com":{"descriptor":"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;xxx@Live.com","allow":xxx,"deny":0}}

        }]
}
```

You can change the the value of allow and deny to change the permission.

Comment: Thanks Perry - I can write the script to update the values but I just don't know what the default values for RepoV2 were to begin with. That's what I need to know. I assume its quite similar for most tenants if they have not customized it. Was wondering if someone could share the identities and access/deny values in the acesdictionary for their environment so I can duplicate the same. I think it has "Project Collection Administrators"(32630,0), "Project Collection Build Service Accounts"(2,0) and "Project Collection Service Accounts"(32630,0)...but not sure what others.